# Cannot create android emulator because image fails to download

Tags: android-studio, android-image

[I tried to download an android image in android studio but it keeps giving me this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lNwT.png).

Answer (score 0):

This is due to slow internet speed. The error is Read Time out. Try to stop everything else on the internet then again download it or use 3g or 4g data package on your sim, connect your system through the hotspot and then download, it will give you a great speed.